# Caps lock + letters A to l not working on mac USB keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb, macos

I am on the verge on snapping my brand new 27" iMacs keyboard. It's the latest USB model. I can't even login to my system because my password contains the letters I have said are not working. All was working fine yesterday.

I can confirm caps lock and letters A to L are not responding. Every other key works as expected.

Has anyone got any ideas before the keyboard becomes two and the iMac goes out the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a hardware issue - the keyboard is f***ed, FYI: I typed this question on my iPad ;)

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a hardware problem you should be able to replace it under the warranty if no liquid was spilled over it.

Answer (score 2):

Can we assume the you typed this question on a computer other than that iMac?

If the computer you're using to type this is a Macintosh with a USB port try plugging the keyboard into it and seeing if the same thing happens.

If the keyboard works fine on this second computer the problem is probably with your iMac and will take one kind of sorting out (boot it from an external hard disk to see if the problem is system related or a hardware problem).

If the keyboard doesn't work fine on this second computer take it and the receipt for your new iMac to an Apple store (or do it online or on the phone) and get a new one.

And, if you can't sort this out or don't want to,  your new computer is under warranty, you can always let Apple sort it for you, possibly ending in a new computer.